# Kubernetes V1.11.0 HA cluster CoreDNS PODS not coming up

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, coredns

I am trying to create Kubernetes V1.11.0 HA cluster in Centos 7 server. I have IPV6 disabled on my host.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/

Based on these steps added all three master, coreDNS POD is not coming up, its keep logging below error in /var/log/messages file.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt            0/1       ContainerCreating   0          53m
coredns-78fcdf6894-plmll            0/1       ContainerCreating   0          53m
```

error message:

```
Jul 17 10:09:28 master03 kubelet: E0717 10:09:28.531244   10041 remote_runtime.go:92] RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c" network for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system" network: open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_dad: no such file or directory, failed to clean up sandbox container "8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c" network for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt": NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system" network: failed to get IP addresses for "eth0": <nil>]
Jul 17 10:09:28 master03 kubelet: E0717 10:09:28.531286   10041 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:56] CreatePodSandbox for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system(7caa3f29-89c3-11e8-aa0f-00505693ca30)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c" network for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system" network: open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_dad: no such file or directory, failed to clean up sandbox container "8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c" network for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt": NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system" network: failed to get IP addresses for "eth0": <nil>]
Jul 17 10:09:28 master03 kubelet: E0717 10:09:28.531298   10041 kuberuntime_manager.go:646] createPodSandbox for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system(7caa3f29-89c3-11e8-aa0f-00505693ca30)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c" network for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system" network: open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_dad: no such file or directory, failed to clean up sandbox container "8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c" network for pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt": NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system" network: failed to get IP addresses for "eth0": <nil>]
Jul 17 10:09:28 master03 kubelet: E0717 10:09:28.531358   10041 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod 7caa3f29-89c3-11e8-aa0f-00505693ca30 ("coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system(7caa3f29-89c3-11e8-aa0f-00505693ca30)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system(7caa3f29-89c3-11e8-aa0f-00505693ca30)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system(7caa3f29-89c3-11e8-aa0f-00505693ca30)\" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container \"8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c\" network for pod \"coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt\": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system\" network: open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_dad: no such file or directory, failed to clean up sandbox container \"8cf72126bd4ea7e33806512997d02b51c3f95331701928c52c19d1ddea9d6f9c\" network for pod \"coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt\": NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"coredns-78fcdf6894-8t7bt_kube-system\" network: failed to get IP addresses for \"eth0\": <nil>]"
Jul 17 10:09:28 master03 kubelet: W0717 10:09:28.636173   10041 cni.go:243] CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: cannot find network namespace for the terminated container "88183d8a24dcafca5b04e3a6454e83aca1417a6934f50cd52b3e6fffbae4f272"
Jul 17 10:09:28 master03 kernel: XFS (dm-18): Mounting V4 Filesystem
```

How to fix this error message and bring the coreDNS PODs?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the coreDNS pod requires ipv6 being enabled. This is something that should be fixed in the image or should be made configurable (maybe it is?) I think.

Comment: Let me try to enable IPV6 and check the log files

Comment: enabling IPV6 fixed the issue. Thanks for the input.

Comment: This might be an issue to raise with the coredns developers if you have a legitimate use case that requires ipv6 to be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to enable the IPv6 to my CoreDNS pod to run.

Here is the steps I followed:

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-ipv6-on-centos-rhel-7/

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the value of kernel parameter `ipv6.disable` from 1 to 0 in line:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

# shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on [Coreos Github](https://github.com/coreos/docs/issues/343) that describes exactly your case. And the suggestion to solve the issue was:

> [squeed](https://github.com/squeed): You are using an old version of CNI, which does not work
>   on systems with ipv6 disabled. Please re-enable ipv6 or upgrade CNI.

And regarding the related issue on [CNI Github](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/issues/569) he also mentioned:

> [squeed](https://github.com/squeed): As I already explained, this has been fixed for 6 months.
>   Please upgrade your CNI plugins.

And [jellonek](https://github.com/jellonek) commented:

> This is the question for your deployment software provider, which in
>   your case is probably https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm

However, in cases when you need to turn off ipv6 for some reason, you can install a cluster with [addon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) KubeDNS instead of [CoreDNS](https://github.com/coredns/deployment/tree/master/kubernetes) using [kubeadm](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/32dc6cc08aa0349d44aa3109f0a718cbb51fb101/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/addons/dns/dns.go#L72):

kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --feature-gates=CoreDNS=false

Or you can delete CoreDNS deployment and service, and then apply KubeDNS yaml, which should be [generated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns/kube-dns) or adjusted to your actual cluster configuration.

Here is a function from the [deployAddons.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/aff6daece4dc8b64ebdf229b72672cf89a01a839/cluster/centos/deployAddons.sh#L27) file responsible for deploying kube-dns addon:

```
function deploy_dns {
  echo "Deploying DNS on Kubernetes"
  cp "${KUBE_ROOT}/cluster/addons/dns/kube-dns/kube-dns.yaml.sed" kube-dns.yaml
  sed -i -e "s/\\\$DNS_DOMAIN/${DNS_DOMAIN}/g" kube-dns.yaml
  sed -i -e "s/\\\$DNS_SERVER_IP/${DNS_SERVER_IP}/g" kube-dns.yaml

  KUBEDNS=`eval "${KUBECTL} get services --namespace=kube-system | grep kube-dns | cat"`

  if [ ! "$KUBEDNS" ]; then
    # use kubectl to create kube-dns addon
    ${KUBECTL} --namespace=kube-system create -f kube-dns.yaml

    echo "Kube-dns addon is successfully deployed."
  else
    echo "Kube-dns addon is already deployed. Skipping."
  fi

  echo
}
```

Comment: not only CoreDNS other nginx pod also expect IPv6 to be enabled.

Comment: Perhaps, it's because all pods need CNI driver to setup network during the start.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem without IPv6 enabling 
(with help from https://www.facebook.com/groups/k8skr)

So, the reason is that, default `Kubernetes CNI` of Ubuntu is 0.6.0.
But the problem is fixed with  `Kubernetes CNI 0.7.0`
So you can update it through download from the below site and replace bin files to `/opt/cni/bin/`

https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases/tag/v0.7.1

At least, it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with the reference of these links

check with kubernates troubleshooting guide and the networking plugin addons you have used

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#coredns-or-kube-dns-is-stuck-in-the-pending-state

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/

And install the following with those and check

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```